# store sessions into a common database

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies

Basically what I am trying to do is sharing session between laravel applications using a common database.
what I've tried so far is

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=login_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_DATABASE_ADMIN=login_admin
DB_USERNAME_ADMIN=root
DB_PASSWORD_ADMIN=
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_CONNECTION=login_admin //getting error here: Database [login_admin] not configured.
```

**session.php**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
'table' => 'sessions',
```

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

'mysql2' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_ADMIN', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_ADMIN', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
]
```

so here I want to set the `sessions` table into my common database named `login_admin`

> I am already sharing a common users table between the projects so I've no issue on connecting multiple databases.
>   I've checked previous relevant questions but did not find how to share the table into common database

Comment: Can you also provide us with the code you are using?

Comment: I am just configuring it, I have not coded anything new

Comment: How do you setup your database with the admin credentials? It looks like your database does not exist at all, so your credentials of admin are not cached.

Comment: How us the ```config/database.php```. hide passwords

Comment: I have configured database.php for multiple databases and its working fine with common `users` table, I have not configured anything for session on `database.php` @hmrneves

Comment: @pr1nc3 I am already loging in with that database, it has no issue

Comment: ```SESSION_CONNECTION=login_admin```, login_admin should be the connection name, not the database. You need to share the code otherwise its difficult to help.

Comment: @hmrneves updated, so you are saying that it will be `mysql2` as my config?

Comment: @Moshiur, yes, change to mysql2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Session Database Connection
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
> | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
> | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
> |
> */
> ```

According to your code `SESSION_CONNECTION` field should be the connection name, which is `mysql2` in your case and not `login_admin`

Comment: Already answered in the comments,. You should let the person who answered write the proper answer here. ;) Regards

Comment: After OP updated his question with the extra details i just pasted the answer, seeing his database.php file. If you check the comments i also discussed it with him

Comment: its the connection name where I was blind at :( thanks for your time